# Using the filling color of cell in conditional formatting rules

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-office

I have some cells with some different filling colors.I want to do the following thing: I want to use those colors in conditional formatting rules, so when I change the color of a cell, the conditional formatting color will change too.
[Like in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcPKs.png)

In the screenshot above, there is a zone called "Legendă". So when I change the color of a cell there, the others cells with the same color will change too. The other cells have conditional formatting rule.

Comment: I don't think you can do it with formulas and conditional formatting in easy way and for general case. I would go for vba with Worksheet_SelectionChange event.

Comment: In general, formatting is not considered source data in Excel.  There is a workaround, however.  Say you were formatting column B and wanted those colors to modify formatting elsewhere.  The idea is to create another column and add your data there, and then use a conditional formatting formula for column B (and any other columns) that refers to your new data.  In this way, you can get as many columns as you want to respond appropriately.

Comment: @Choirbean, I'd suggest that **is** the answer, and to post it as an answer.

Comment: Done, and thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

In general, formatting is not considered source data in Excel.  The workaround, then, is to put the information in a new column.

Say you were formatting column B and wanted those colors to modify formatting elsewhere. The idea is to create another column and add your data there, and then create a conditional formatting formula for column B (and any other columns) that refers to your new data. This way, you can get as many columns as you want to respond appropriately.